# Is breakthrough-starshot the best tag, and should the project-starshot tag now be a synonym for it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

We have [breakthrough-starshot](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breakthrough-starshot) (**3** questions) and [project-starshot](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-starshot)  (**8** questions) and the Wikipedia article [Breakthrough Starshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakthrough_Starshot) says:

> **Breakthrough Starshot is a research and engineering project by the Breakthrough Initiatives** to develop a proof-of-concept fleet of light sail interstellar probes named Starchip, to be capable of making the journey to the Alpha Centauri star system 4.37 light-years away. It was founded in 2016 by Yuri Milner, Stephen Hawking, and Facebook founder Mark Zuckerberg.
>
> A flyby mission has been proposed to Proxima Centauri b, an Earth-sized exoplanet in the habitable zone of its host star, Proxima Centauri, in the Alpha Centauri system.[4] At a speed between 15% and 20% of the speed of light, it would take between twenty and thirty years to complete the journey, and approximately four years for a return message from the starship to Earth.
>
> The conceptual principles to enable this interstellar travel project were described in "A Roadmap to Interstellar Flight", by Philip Lubin of UC Santa Barbara. Sending the lightweight spacecraft involves a multi-kilometer phased array of beam-steerable lasers with a combined coherent power output of up to 100 GW.

**Question:** So based on Wikipedia think that [breakthrough-starshot](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breakthrough-starshot) is what we should use, and the [project-starshot](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-starshot) tag should be synonymized to it. What do others think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree. Merge and synonymize [project-starshot](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-starshot) into [breakthrough-starshot](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breakthrough-starshot).

Comment: Thanks. I think this one is pretty cut-and-dried but hopefully a few more folks will up vote your answer as well.